# When a template class has an instantiation of another template class with a template member function

Tags: c++, templates

I am confused by the fact that GCC does not compile the following code:

```
template<typename num>
struct A
{
  template<int y>
  num run(num x) { return x + y; }
};

template<typename num>
struct B
{
  A<num> a;
  num run(num x)
  {
    if (x > 1) return a.run<1>(x);
    return a.run<0>(x);
  }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double test(double x) 
{
  B<double> b;
  return b.run(x);
}
```

The error message is `invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator<’ --- if (x > 1) return a.run<1>(x);`.

However, by removing the template on `struct B`, the following compiles:

```
template<typename num>
struct A
{
  template<int y>
  num run(num x) { return x + y; }
};

struct B
{
  A<double> a;
  double run(double x)
  {
    if (x > 1) return a.run<1> (x);
    return a.run<0> (x);
  }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double test(double x) 
{
  B b;
  return b.run(x);
}
```

Additionally, if I remove the `test` function from the first piece of code, it also compiles.

What change should be made to make the first piece of code work, or is it just inherently wrong? I am using GCC-8.5.

Upate: according to the kind comments, the code should be changed to:

```
template<typename num>
struct A
{
  template<int y>
  num run(num x) { return x + y; }
};

template<typename num>
struct B
{
  A<num> a;
  num run(num x)
  {
    if (x > 1) return a.template run<1>(x);
    return a.template run<0>(x);
  }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double test(double x) 
{
  B<double> b;
  return b.run(x);
}
```

Nice.

Comment: [Fix the warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/Ef1GTEKPf).

Comment: Looks like gcc improved things by adding `warning: expected 'template' keyword before dependent template name`.

Comment: [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245)

Comment: Myself: *"Looks like gcc improved"* I meant to include a version number: gcc **12**.